# Changing Font Size of Node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am new to TkiZ. I am trying to decrease the font size of a node locally.

Tried to read the below (Page 224):

```
http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf
```

The changes are not taking effect. Hope you can guide me on what could have be done wrongly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart, shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{rec} = [rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=3, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, align=left, draw=black, fill=blue!30] 

\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=1.5cm]

\node (rec1) [rec] {\nodepart{two}
\textbf{Node: Normal Size Text}
\\\# Text 1
\\\# Text 2
\\\# Text 3
};

\node (rec2) [rec, below of=rec1, yshift=-1cm, font=\small] {\nodepart{two} %Attempt 1: not working
%\node (rec2) [rec, below of=rec1, yshift=-1cm, style={font=\small}] {\nodepart{two} %Attempt 2: not working
%\node (rec2) [rec, below of=rec1, yshift=-1cm] {\nodepart{two} \small %Attempt 3: not working
\textbf{Node: Small Size Text}
\\\# Text 1
\\\# Text 2
\\\# Text 3
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\tikzset` rather than `\tikzstyle`, by the way. (The latter is considered deprecated.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you are using `minimal` document class which doesn't provide font size commands like `\small`. Use `standalone` or `article` or `book`.... instead

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.multipart, shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{rec/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=3, 
  minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm, align=left, draw=black, fill=blue!30}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=1.5cm]

\node (rec1) [rec] {\nodepart{two}
\textbf{Node: Normal Size Text}
\\\# Text 1
\\\# Text 2
\\\# Text 3
};

\node (rec2) [rec, below of=rec1, yshift=-1cm, font=\small] {\nodepart{two} %Attempt 1: not working
%\node (rec2) [rec, below of=rec1, yshift=-1cm, style={font=\small}] {\nodepart{two} %Attempt 2: not working
%\node (rec2) [rec, below of=rec1, yshift=-1cm] {\nodepart{two} \small %Attempt 3: not working
\textbf{Node: Small Size Text}
\\\# Text 1
\\\# Text 2
\\\# Text 3
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Bottom line

*Never use* `minimal` unless you know what you are doing. For further details, please visit and read:

[why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: You could add a link to our canonical question on this topic: [Why should the `minimal` class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided) so readers can dig for the full details if desired.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks, I guessed that some thing should be there already but couldn't locate it. Now I have added the link.

Comment: Thanks for all the guidance. It works like a charm. The link by Paul Gessler is most useful. Learnt a number of tips.